# Star-shaped set

Tags: real-analysis

*Definition*.- A set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called *star-shaped* if there exists a point $z_0$in $S$ such that the line segment between $z_0$ and any point $z$ in $S$ is contained in $S$, $z_0$ is called a center of $S$.

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a *star-shaped*  open  set , I have a problem is the set $$ \color{blue}Z=\{z\in S:z \text{ is a center of S}\}$$ an open set ?

and if $S$ is bounded ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Sorry for the typo, i have edited.

Comment: It needn't be. $Z$ can consist of a single point. Spikes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yikes... spikes? =)

Comment: How can $Z$ consist of a single point

Comment: @EnjoysMath Spikes.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yi...

Comment: Whoever voted to close this is just showing their lack of imagination (or perhaps their intolerance of non-native-English speakers). As I understand it, the problem is this: Is the set of centers of S an open set?

Comment: A star-shaped set has to be connected, right? So that stipulation is unnecessary.

Comment: @TonyK, there were $3$ close votes, including one by me, before the question was edited. After the edit one other user  and I removed our close votes. Probably the remaining user hasn't seen the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a right-angled triangle that is not isosceles.  Fit four of them around a single point, like a pinwheel.

EDIT: Take the interior of the octagon with vertices (in order) $(0,2),(0,1),(2,0),(1,0),(0,-2),(0,-1),(-2,0),(-1,0)$

Comment: I don't see it.  How would this work since $S$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The set

$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : |y| < \frac1{1+x^2}\}$$

is open and star-shaped (with $z_0 = (0,0)$, for instance). But all its centers lie on the line $y=0$, so your set $Z$ has no interior points.

**Updated to answer the updated question:**

If $S$ is bounded, the answer is still no. The details are a bit messy, but in essence, we can define an "infinite open daisy" with a hub equal to the open unit disk, and an infinite number of "open petals" of length 2, which get narrower and narrower as they approach the y-axis. The only center is $(0,0)$.

**Updated to add:** As Steve's comment and Aldo's answer show, the details don't need to be messy.

Comment: How about the interior of a hypocycloid, e.g., the region defined by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3} < 1$?

Answer (score 2):

If you take the open unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and remove the (closure of the) first quadrant, you get an open star shaped set, with center $(-x,-x)$ for any $0 < x< \sqrt{2} $. There are, of course, many more centers for this set, for instance the points of the form $(0,y)$ with $-1<y<0$.

Any point $(x,y)$ with $0<x$ and $-1<y<0$ won't be a center, therefore the set of centers is not open.